# Sql query unable to parse query text

Tags: vb.net, t-sql

I have tried creating a SQL query in vb and i keep getting an error. Here is my code:

```
SELECT userid, Email, [password], [First Name]
     , [Last Name], [Date of Birth], Major
FROM   Students
WHERE  userid = @StudentIdParam AND [password] = @studentPassParam
```

And the error is as follows:

> error in WHERE clause near '@' unable to parse query text.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: tell us what database you are using

Comment: What the classes you are using ? Are you using SqlCommand and SqlParameters? I think you are not using the XParameters class thats why the XCommand is unable to resolve the parameters.

Answer (score 1):

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@StudentIdParam", studentIdParam)
cmd.Parameters.Add("@studentPassParam", studentPassParam)
```

...before executing the query.